# Symfony2 - mapping two tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want to join two tables (`games` and `ownership`). From there, I want to print those Games which user has assigned to him in Ownership. For example: user (id: 2) has two games (id: 1 and id:2). I want to print only these two.

My controller is as follows:

```
function getGameAction($id) {
    $game = $this->getDoctrine()
      ->getRepository('GameShelfGamesBundle:Game')
      ->find($id);

    return new Response($game->getOwnership()->getName());
}
```

Entities: [Ownership](http://pastebin.com/nXj23edq) and [Game](http://pastebin.com/XYs4g7z0).

For now, I only get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Proxies__CG__\GameShelf\UsersBundle\Entity\Ownership::getName() in D:!!XAMPP\htdocs\Symfony\src\GameShelf\GamesBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php on line 50

Comment: Your `Ownership` entity doesn't have a `getName()` function. What exactly are you trying to print?

Answer (score 0):

Look at error message - you don't have either any getOwnership method or even relation with ownership table.

For first you need in you game entity declare relation with ownership:

```
/*
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Namespace\To\Ownership", inversedBy="games")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ownership_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $ownership;
```

And in your Ownership entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Namespace\To\Game", mappedBy="ownership")
 */
private $games;
```

Then run console command to generate setters and getters and everything should goes fine.

Comment: No, I've made a mistake. What I think I need is ManyToMany. You see, many users, many games, each user can own particaul game, many games can have certain "own" state and be "owned" by user. How can I achieve this? It's been four days of diggin thru docs and I'm square one again.

Comment: Take a break for a day.  Then slog through the manual: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html and actually make your product/categories and understand what is going on.  Make yourself a Command object so you can test the stuff easily.  Then work you way through the Doctrine chapter on associations, http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html and see how many-to-many relations work.  Might take a few days but it will be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to add a variable named "name" in your Ownership-Entity. Therefore you don't have any getters and setters automatically generated.
Try to put all your variables at the beginning of your code @Cyprian oversaw your relation because of that.

If you just look at the errormessage you should instantly see where your error is coming from.